# Correct way of integrating Spring Boot + EFK in docker production environment?

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, logback, fluentd, logstash-logback-encoder

I am not finding a correct & efficient way to collect logs from spring boot docker to Elasticsearch via Fluentd in docker environment. My config as below

**Dockerfile for spring-boot jar**:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG JAR_FILE=target/user-management.jar

EXPOSE 10010

COPY ${JAR_FILE} user-management.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "user-management.jar"]
```

**Logback configuration** - logback.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/tests.log</file>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <logger name="jsonLogger" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.xyz.usermanagement" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**Fluentd configuration** - fluent.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<label @FLUENT_LOG>
  <match *.**>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host elasticsearch
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix fluentd
      logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
      include_tag_key true
      type_name access_log
      tag_key @log_name
      flush_interval 5s
    </store>
    <store>
      @type stdout
    </store>
  </match>
</label>
```

Below is the docker-compose which I am using to build the services

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearchsrvc
    image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    volumes:
      - elasticsearchdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - microservicesntwrk
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  fluentd:
    container_name: fluentdsrvc
    image: fluentdimg:0.0.1
    build:
      context: ../fluentd/
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
    networks:
      - microservicesntwrk
    ports:
      - 24224:24224

  kibana:
    container_name: kibanasrvc
    image: kibana:7.10.1
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearchsrvc:9200
    networks:
      - microservicesntwrk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601

  usermanagement:
    container_name: usermanagementsrvc
    image: usermanagementimg:0.0.1
    build:
      context: ../business/user-management
    depends_on:
      - fluentd
    ports:
      - 10010:10010
    networks:
      - microservicesntwrk

volumes:
  elasticsearchdata:
    driver: local


networks:
  microservicesntwrk:
    driver: bridge
    name: microservicesntwrk
```

I am able to see the logs generated by the Fluentd service in elastic search but not the logs generated by the usermanagement (Spring-Boot) docker container.

Any direction on this is appreciated, Thanks.